# Is conversion from Decimal type to Single type a narrowing conversion or a widening conversion?

Tags: c#, .net

In Single struct and Decimal struct document at Ms Docs that says about type conversion from Decimal to Single, the former says it's widening conversion and latter says it's narrowing conversion. Which one is right?
And I don't get how the magnitude of the Decimal type could be preserved when converted to Single type. Please explain.

Comment: Please add a link to the documents that you are talking about.

Comment: The *magnitude* will be preserved, but the precision won't

Comment: Sorry my bad, here are the links that talks about Single and Decimal type respectively. Single: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/dotnet/api/system.single?view=netframework-4.8#type-conversions-and-the-single-structure) Decimal: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/dotnet/api/system.decimal?view=netframework-4.8#conversion-considerations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking, conversion from Decimal to Single is neither *narrowing* nor *widening*. Decimal has a **narrower range** than a Single but it has a **wider precision**.

Conversion from Decimal to Single will never throw an `OverflowException` but it can lead to a loss of information. That is why there is no Implicit conversion in either direction.

The range of a Single is ±1.5 x 10<sup>−45</sup> to ±3.4 x 10<sup>38</sup> compared to the range of a Decimal of ±1.0 x 10<sup>−28</sup> to ±7.9228 x 10<sup>28</sup>. So both the smallest possible Decimal and the largest possible Decimal can fit in a Single without overflow. The magnitude of the Decimal will be maintained.

However, the precision of a Single is only around 6-9 digits (in base 10) compared to 28-29 digits in a Decimal. So if you convert a Decimal to a Single, any of the digits after the sixth-ninth will be lost. There is a potential loss of information, but not a loss of the magnitude of the number.

[More Information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types)

You ask how it is possible that the magnitude of a Decimal stored in 12 bytes can fit in a Single of only 4 bytes. The reason is that decimal/floating point numbers are not stored as a direct conversion to binary - part of the storage is used for the magnitude (like the "times 10 to the power of" in scientific format) and part is used for the binary equivalent of the digits themselves.

Comment: To my understanding Decimal type has much larger storage space than Single type, so at first I thought casting and assigning a Decimal typed value to Single type variable would affect it's magnitude too. But like you said it seems magnitude is preserved, if you try to print it out the hidden rest of the data because of the limited precision of the Single data type using more larger data type like Double. So this confuses me.

Comment: By assigning Decimal value to smaller Single type variable I thought during that process the part of the original magnitude should be truncated or affected in someway, but despite the smaller size of the Single type the magnitude is preserved, how could this be possible?

Comment: I will add some more details to my answer to help.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer, it helped a lot.